# Script# and compiler problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, script#

I've just come across a pretty strange problem with VS2010 and Script#, which most of the time I am able to re-create.

In my simple scenario I have 2 projects in my solution; a standard Asp.Net MVC2 Web Application, and a Script# jQuery Class Library. I created a static class (attributed with [Imported]) with a static method on it, the intention being that I can map this class in code to an external Javascript library, as described in the documentation.

However, it seems that whenever I decorate such a class with [IgnoreNamespace] to achieve this goal, the project stops successfully compiling but doesn't give me any feedback as to why it's failing (no errors in the error window, for example). It's not easy to get rid of either, as Visual Studio seems to get into a permanent state of not build failure; removing the classes and project files doesn't solve it, nor restarting visual studio. The only way I can get VS to build the project successfully is to delete the project entirely, create a new one then add the files back in, which is annoying to say the least.

With a verbose build output setting, I get the following:

Target "AfterCompile" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\ScriptSharp\v1.0\ScriptSharp.targets" from project "e:\project\local\ScriptSharpDemo\Scripts\Scripts.csproj" (target "Compile" depends on it):
Task "ScriptCompilerTask"
Done executing task "ScriptCompilerTask" -- FAILED.
Done building target "AfterCompile" in project "Scripts.csproj" -- FAILED.

.. which doesn't tell me whole lot.

There have been a couple of times where I have managed to create this type of class and then successfully build, but mostly I can reproduce this problem pretty reliably.

At this point I'm inclined to think that the bug lies with Script#, but would just like to have that confirmed, and to find a possible work around if there is one.

Comment: You should trim down your class you're trying to import and post it here.

Comment: Also, are you using the latest version of the compiler? Try 0.6.1.0 if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I've realised that this problem occurs only if you choose the 'Add Class..' item when trying to insert a new class into the Script# project, rather than choose 'Add Item..' then choosing a Script# class from there. As soon as you add a class using the first method, it renders the project unusable.

And it does make sense; I obviously have to add an item to the project using the correct method. Even though the resulting file looks exactly the same, S# obviously knows the difference and doesn't like it. Unfortunately it's an easy mistake to make when you're in the zone :(

Comment: I have just come across this again, except this time I added a new class using the correct method. I just went to Add Item -> Script# -> Class, tried to rebuild the project and it now says Build Failed, without any error messages. I've tried removing the file, clean/rebuild project but nothing works. I don't suppose you've ever come across this during your development? 

Is there some sort of compiler cache I can clear out to get to it to start building again, without re-creating the entire project?

I'm using 0.6.2, but as above this happened with 0.6.1 as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case anyone is having a similar issue, I've found the cause of the problem.

When adding a class using this method, or copying in a file from another project for use within Script#, this causes a reference to System.dll to be added to the project. This (understandably) causes the project to stop compiling without error.

It would be nice to have a warning about this or for Script# to somehow detect when this situation occurs and/or create a new template for when I use 'Add class' or import a file, but it is just a convenience issue and at least now I can painlessly get my project compiling again just by removing this reference.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to make my project build again, I came across the following, possible solutions:

- The "Home\HomePage.cs" and "Shared\Utility.cs" must not be deleted and remain where they wre initially created
- The "Home\HomePage.cs" and "Shared\Utility.cs" must be the last entries in the "*.csproj"-file. After them, no "Compile" tag should follow
- Problematic calls to "Script.Literal" might cause silent fails - especially be careful when having parameters (like `Script.Literal("{0}.doFoo()", variable)`)
- The same seems to be true for "String.Format" when the format parameters are invalid
- Namespaces and folders seem to cause many problems, putting all classes into the same namespace and all classes into the same folder might help

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the suggestions that have been given here, but continued to see the issue.  Eventually, I determined that the cause in my situation was that I had added an [IntrinsicProperty] attribute to one of my properties.  Removing it solved the issue.  Don't ask me why this was causing a problem, but I thought I would share this solution in case others run into it.